# Fragment callbacks explosion, how to deal?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments, android-activity, callback

I am creating my app with using fragments. I have something like main activity, it has `FrameLayout` as root layout to hold fragments.
After much thought I have decided to separate my application logic in several parts, for example : `MainActivity` is responsible for app basic navigation (`MainPageFragment, CategoryListFragment, ProductListFragment, ProductDescriptionFragment`), `AuthActivity` is responsible for autherization, registration (`SignInFragment, RegistrationFragment, RecoverPasswordFragment`).
A little about my app. If you have recommendation or don't agree with app structure, I would be grateful for any critics.

What is the problem, as you can see my MainActivity has many responsibilities. There are four Fragments now but it can be more in the future.
Lets consider next situation. In my MainActivity I have MainPageFragment and this fragment in turn of course has some views. And on click event I need to change fragment, for instance from MainPageFragment to the CategoryListFragment. In this case I have several ways to handle clicks or other events from framgents.

1. The most common way is to have activity implements callback interface defined in fragment class as nested class inteface. This approach is quite good and easy to use. But what if my host activity has to handle multiple callbacks from fragments, to say more, there can be more than one callback from single fragment, class(activity) declaration starts growing, class body too. What are another possible approaches to solve this problem.
2. You can handle all clicks, events directly inside fragment (start activity, replace framgent......) you can do this painless, but for me personally callback approach looks better, but maybe there is nothing bad, and I can use this approach.
3. Use one or several interfaces for getting information from fragments. For example create class `CallbackEvent` for holding such info as `framgentId, eventType` .... Using this approach we can reduce interfaces and methods, but Activity class body can become larger in first approach.
4. Use something like EventBus pattern to communicate between app components via third party service.

Of course there are some other ways to do this, but I have described most popular.

Please suggest, or just explain how to do you solve this problem in your apps, what approach is better, how to built this communication easy to maintain.

I am grateful for any advice,critics in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you are looking for ways to deal with clicks in fragments and communicate them with the activity without adding too much code ?

Comment: not only clicks but there can be another events that require some actions.

Comment: All fragments know their parent activity, so instead of implementing a callback interface you could just call `getActivity().doSomething()` in your fragment.

Comment: I know this, but it proved to be bad practice. In this case fragment knows about your exact Activity implementation not Activity  but MyActivity and specific method of my activity class derived from base Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your app becomes more complex using the callback pattern will get messy, especially if fragments need to communicate with fragments. I'd only use that pattern for apps with low complexity (activity, one or two fragments).
2. Clicks, events etc. should be handled inside a fragment if whatever happens stays within the fragment. Don't replace a fragment from within the fragment, that's the Activity's responsibility. It might look easier to just do a getActivity().someMethod in the fragment but this leads to hard to maintain code. You might understand now what it's doing but will struggle in half a year.
3. This approach looks messy to me too (similar to 1.)
4. That's the one I'd recommend. I'm using EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) but there are alternative implementations like Otto (https://github.com/square/otto) and I've never looked back to the times when I used the callback pattern. Using an EventBus decouples the communication between the different components and your code becomes much simpler and leaner. However you need to be careful with that approach since there are some pitfalls. One is that it gets much easier to communicate from any component to any other component which could lead to even messier code than the listener/observer pattern. Another one is that events are asynchronous compared to synchronous listener calls so you need to make sure you're only receiving the "right" events at the right moment in the component's lifecycle. The main advantages of an EventBus approach are IMO:

   - A message is always an object forcing the developer to code object oriented compared to the more functional listener method calls
   - It decouples the different components. Publisher and subscribers don't have to know about each other. Decoupling the components will make your code much leaner and easier to read (and maintain).
   - It can be used by arbitrary components. E.g. I replaced all LocalBroadcastManager calls by EventBus messages (EventBus is MUCH faster that using a LocalBroadcastManager). Being able to communicate between arbitrary components is especially convenient if the components can't access each other directly (like a Dialog and a Preference object)

Comment: Thank you for great answer, I also think that using EventBus can be helpful in this case. But, this approach has something similar with third one. You also have to implement Event class and handle events determine if you need, from what component this message came from. Don't you think so ?

Comment: The element these two approaches share is the event object I agree but that's about all they have in common. You'd still need to register listeners on one or the other components (or both ways) while there's no direct interaction between the components with the event bus approach. Each component can do their "thing" without even knowing if there's a subscriber or publisher for a certain event.

Comment: Thank, I will use EventBus it pretended to be great solution

Answer (score 1):

I have two rules of Fragment - Activity separation.

One is logic. Anything that deals with View (layout expansion, display, listeners, etc) should go inside a Fragment. Important background processes (http requests, file reading, image processing, etc) should go inside Activity. Part of the reason is explained in my second point:

Lifecycle. Activity's lifecycle outlasts Fragment's. Fragment is also fragile it doesn't even retain its views. And this is the reason Fragment should be decoupled from Activity. Listeners and callbacks are tight coupling and they are the cause of countless null pointer exceptions when some process tries to update a View of a Fragment that has called its `onDestroyView`. Having said this I'd suggest Publisher - Subscriber pattern like Event Bus where you can plan a message delivery in which it gets digested only when a publisher (which in this case corresponds to Fragment's view) is available.

The numerous click listeners you have are related to how you design your UI. Moving code around doesn't really help much, unless you trim down your layouts.